# How to categorize textures into atlases

Tags: unity, textures, shaders, texture-atlas

I am going to use texture atlasing for the first time in my games, and at first it seemed like a great idea to split textures into atlases by categorizing them by terrain themes e.g *ForestTextures*, *WinterTextures* etc.

But that could cause a problem when for example a flower has to use transparency shader and other models use a diffuse shader. So those cannot be atlased into the same texture. Thus, would atlasing textures into themes as mentioned before and then splitting them by shader like *ForestDiffuse* and *ForestTransparent* be good? Or is there a better way to categorize and build them?

Answer (score 1):

Because the whole purpose of atlasing is to reduce draw calls by using fewer materials, you definitely want to categorize by material, rather than a theme. It may seem backwards at first, but categorizing by "theme" is actually an arbitrary way to categorize them. Don't constrain yourself to themes; instead, think of your atlas in terms surface and material type.